# Check if position of element is equal to top: 50%; and left: 50%;

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this function (it determines whether `grid-container` in inside of `grid-container-wrapper` and if not it moves `grid-container` to the middle of the page with `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;`.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right > document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container-wrapper')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right || document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom > document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container-wrapper')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom || $('.grid-container').position().left < $('.grid-container-wrapper').position().left || $('.grid-container').position().top < $('.grid-container-wrapper').position().top) {
            $('.grid-container').animate({opacity:0}, 200, function() {
                $('.grid-container').css('top', '50%');
                $('.grid-container').css('left', '50%');
                $('.grid-container').css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%)');
            } );

            $('.grid-container').animate({opacity:1}, 400);
        }
    });
```

However, if `grid-container` is already positioned with `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;` AND HASN'T BEEN MOVED (so the position is still equal to `left: 50%;` and `top: 50%;`), I do not want the function to be executed, even if `grid-container` is outisde of `grid-container-wrapper`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right > document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container-wrapper')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right || document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom > document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container-wrapper')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom || $('.grid-container').position().left < $('.grid-container-wrapper').position().left || $('.grid-container').position().top < $('.grid-container-wrapper').position().top) {
        if(window.innerWidth - document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right + 20 < $('.grid-container').position().left || window.innerWidth - document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right - 20 > $('.grid-container').position().left || document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container-wrapper')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom - document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 20 < $('.grid-container').position().top || document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container-wrapper')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom - document.getElementsByClassName('grid-container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 20 > $('.grid-container').position().top) {
            $('.grid-container').animate({opacity:0}, 200, function() {
                $('.grid-container').css('top', '50%');
                $('.grid-container').css('left', '50%');
                $('.grid-container').css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -50%)');
            } );

            $('.grid-container').animate({opacity:1}, 400);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already positioned with top: 50%; and left: 50% you can add a class like 'stopResisize' to the grid-container or any other field and when the resize function is started just look if this class exists. If so than return without doing anything.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($('.grid-container').classList.contains("stopResisize")) return;
  if ( ... ) {
    ...
    $('.grid-container').classList.add('stopResisize');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I can move ```grid-container```. I only want the function not be executed when it hasn't been moved and the position is still equal to ```left: 50%``` and ```top: 50%```. I edited the question.